# ansible - iterate list error: 'item' is undefined

Tags: list, ansible

I have below ospf process:

```
msg: ' OSPF Process: [''T1'', ''T2'', ''T3'']'

    ospf_process:
    - T1
    - T2
    - T3
```

I have below task to shut ospf process but isn't working. ansible is throwing error.

```
  - name: Shut OSPF process
    cisco.nxos.nxos_config:
      lines:
      - shutdown
      parents: router ospf {{item}}
      with_items: "{{ ospf_process }}"
      save_when: modified
```

Error is:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, `with_items` should be an argument to the task, not the `nxos_config` module. You need:

```
  - name: Shut OSPF process
    cisco.nxos.nxos_config:
      lines:
      - shutdown
      parents: router ospf {{item}}
      save_when: modified
    with_items: "{{ ospf_process }}"
```